# Releasing properties

Tags: objective-c

I have two NSStrings and those are also having the property, synthesize. Is there any need to release those objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the property is either copy or retain you have to release the ivar. If the value is just assigned you must not release.

Comment: In many cases this is true, but it's not 100% accurate. There are cases when objects get put on the autorelease pool where you do not have to release the objects.

Comment: Imho it is 100% accurate. If your object has ivars that get autoreleased you are doing something wrong, because you could never access them later (ie you get a BAD_ACCESS or you wouldn't need them in the first place). One moment, I'll make a little sample project for you.

Comment: @DasBoot if you are still interested, I made a little sample http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2414726/PropertySample.zip StringCollection has two MyString objects which both get created trough an [objectWith:] method that returns an [[... alloc] init] autorelease] object. Both get "assigned" with a setter and only one is released in dealloc. The NSLog shows that only the released one gets deallocated. I would be very happy to see a similar example that shows that I'm not 100% accurate :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Anything which is pointer type which is made property & synthesise should be released

Comment: unless there is an `assign` directive in the property. Like it should be with delegates for example.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you should call release actually depends.

If you called alloc+init, and then assigned to the property, then you do have to release. The reason is that alloc+init increases the reference count by 1, so you have to have a corresponding release to return the reference count to 0. The release should be in the dealloc method of the class.

However, it's possible to use those properties without calling alloc+init too. Then generally you don't have to call release. For example if you use self.property = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"..."], then there is no need to call release, actually calling release would be wrong.

Furthermore, you may also decide to autorelease objects, which tells the autorelease pool to automatically release objects at a later time. This is another case where you don't have to manually release the object.

Comment: Nope, you are wrong. If the app doesn't crash on the next access of `self.property` then there was a `retain` or `copy` directive in the property. And then you have to release!

Comment: @fluchtpunkt: Why do you think this is wrong? In my example the stringWithFormat class method autoreleases the object for you. There is no need for you to release it. And, I'm also assuming that there is a retain or copy directive in the property.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly he is asking if he should release the ivar for which he has used the synthesized setter.

Comment: @fluchtpunkt: Yeah. That's what I understood too. But, why do I have to explicitly call a release? I don't understand your comment. Again, going back to my example, I think I can do this:  self.property = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"..."], and not call [property release]. Is your statement that this is wrong?

Comment: yes this is wrong. the "..." string will never get deallocated, because it is retained (or copied which also increases the retain) when you "assign" (not in the @property assign sense) it through the synthesized property.